# nestjsx/crud: How do define an alias for a filter field

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, nest

I have a nested typeorm OneToOne field in my model, call it `Entity.related_entity`. It's exposed to the API through the use of Nest/Crud endpoint.

I want to use the CRUD filter to filter on the `related_entity` fields, but currently it's only possible via `?filter=related_entity.some_field||$eq||10`. How to make it so that it's possible to filter like this `?filter=some_field||$eq||10`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to register an alias for a filter. Assuming you are using the `@Crud` decorator on your controller, I think your best option would be the `filter` attribute of the `query` option (documented [here](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#filter)). It allows you to register a function to transform your query search condition. In your case, you could have something like the following. Note that I have not tested that code and it might not work "as is", it is simply meant to give an idea of what the solution could look like.

```js
function findAndReplaceAliases(search: SCondition) {
  search.$and.map((filter) =>
    filter.keys().contains('some_field')
      ? { 'related_entity.some_field': filter['some_field'] }
      : filter
  );
}

@Crud({
  query: {
    filter: findAndReplaceAliases
  }
})
@Controller()
SomeController {}
```